# jquery selectors: an uncommon use case

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-selectors, cheerio

I have to parse an html page organized this way:

```
<li id="list">
  <a id="cities">Cities</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="region" title="liguria">Liguria</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="genova">Genova</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="savona">Savona</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="region" title="lazio">Lazio</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="roma">Roma</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I need to extract a list of all the **cities**. I don't care about regions...
I am using *cheerio* from *node.js*, but I added jquery to the tags since *cheerio* uses jquery-style selector (AFAIK...).

I have come with this partial solution, partially working (it only lists first region group cities...):

```
$('li[id="list"] li li').each(function(i, elem) {
  console.log('city:', elem.children[0].next.children[0].data);
});
```

As you can see, I'm quite confused... :-(
Any clue?

Comment: @James Donnelly: yes, thanks, corrected... The data I report here is an abstraction of my real data, so... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`$('li#list ul li ul li a').each(function() {
    console.error("City: "+$(this).html());
});`

As noted below, the selector could be simply `$('li#list li li a')`.

Comment: `#list li li a` should be enough (as a selector).

Comment: True: I actually lengthened it just so as to be clear.

Comment: Both solutions list only the cities of the first region... :-(

Comment: @MarcoS No, they are not, if the structure is the same in your example as in your real data.

Comment: @raina77ow: you are right, sorry! Effectively, my real data is a bit different, I must have done some silly mistake. **Thanks, everybody! :-)**

Comment: So, have you got it to work then, or do you need another selector for your different data?

Comment: Working perfectly... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('li[id="list"] ul li').each(function(i, elem) {
     ...work on each li containing the region ...
});
```

Comment: I did accept first answer, but I suppose I will adopt **your** strategy, I feel it's cleaner... :-)

Comment: Sorry, how would you "... work on each li containing the region ...", exactly? I did try with something like `$(this).find('ul li a').each(function(i, elem) { console.log(elem); }`, but it doesn't work... :-(

Comment: try using $(elem).find('ul li a').each(function(i, elem2) { console.log(elem2); } inside the first each for example

Answer (score 0):

**Note** that when using an id selector, since by definition an id is unique, the selector does not need any other qualifiers such as the tag name. And usually you would only use `tagname[id...]` if you're matching a substring in the ID: ^ - at the beginning, $ - at the end or * - anywhere.

Another approach would be to use `:not()` to exclude the `a` elements that should be left out:

```
$('#list a:not(.region,#cities)').each(function(i, a) {
    console.log( i, a.innerHTML );
});
```

You have several options for valid selectors you can use:

- `#list ul ul a`
- `#list li li a`
- `#list ul ul li a`

```js
$('#list a:not(.region,#cities)').each(function(i, a) {
    console.log( i, a.innerHTML );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="list">
  <a id="cities">Cities</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="region" title="liguria">Liguria</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="genova">Genova</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="savona">Savona</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="region" title="lazio">Lazio</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="roma">Roma</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**AND** to get all the cities in an array called `cities` you can use the jQuery `.map()` method:

```
var cities = $('#list li li a').map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
```

```js
var cities = $('#list li li a').map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
console.log( cities );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="list">
  <a id="cities">Cities</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="region" title="liguria">Liguria</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="genova">Genova</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="savona">Savona</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="region" title="lazio">Lazio</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="roma">Roma</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```